# Android XMPP chat single tick mark and how to read h value from logs

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, stanza

I am developing chat app using these two libraries
org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.3
org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.3

the problem is after send the message to user i am getting xmpp stanza acknowledgements like this RCV (1): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='1'/>
how to read this  tag and h value,please help me if any body done this functionality,give links or give code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the h value. Use a stanza acknowledged listener to determine which stanzas have been acknowledged.

Comment: hi thanks for giving response,can you share any example code.

Comment: And how to know the messages are reached xmpp server,how to know the xmpp server is down or not.